# Performing similar operations on multiple objects with only a single call difference?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm attempting to refactor some code written by a previous developer, and I'm scraping my brain trying to come up with a good way to handle this specific use case. We have a method called `ProcessMessage` that has a switch statement to handle some basic string replacement, but each switch case has a specific object type it's fetching, and a specific method it's calling. The rest of the operations are pretty similar.

First and foremost, I simplified the switch, but I think there may be a way to simplify it further. I was thinking using generics might be possible, but unfortunately these objects are Entities generated by a Database-First Entity Framework context, so I can't do much to modify their underlying types or any interfaces they may inherit.

Here's an example of the switch statement and a couple of the helper methods:

```
private string ProcessMessage(int? userId, int? resourceId, int? reminderId, string processedMessage)
{
    var sourceEntityList = _replacementKeywords.Select(x => x.SourceEntity).Distinct().ToList();
    foreach (var sourceEntity in sourceEntityList)
    {
        var sourcekeyWords = _replacementKeywords.Where(x => x.SourceEntity == sourceEntity).Select(x => x.ReplacementText).ToList();
        switch (sourceEntity)
        {
            case "User":
                if (userId.HasValue)
                {
                    var user = _userRepository.GetById(userId);

                    processedMessage = GetReplacementValue(user, sourcekeyWords, processedMessage);
                }

                break;
            case "Reminder":
                if (reminderId.HasValue)
                {
                    var ar = _reminderRepository.GetById(reminderId.Value);

                    processedMessage = GetReplacementValue(ar, sourcekeyWords, processedMessage);
                }

                break;
            case "Resource":
                if (resourceId.HasValue)
                {
                    var scheduleResource = _schedulingRepository.GetresourceIdById(resourceId.Value);

                    processedMessage = GetReplacementValue(scheduleResource, sourcekeyWords, processedMessage);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    return processedMessage;
}

private static string GetReplacementValue(User user, IEnumerable<string> sourceKeywords, string message)
{
    var processedMessage = message;
    foreach (var userKeyword in sourceKeywords)
    {
        if (!processedMessage.Contains(userKeyword)) continue;

        var replaceValue = GetPatientInfoFromUser(user, userKeyword);
        processedMessage = processedMessage.Replace(userKeyword, replaceValue);
    }

    return processedMessage;
}

private static string GetReplacementValue(Reminder reminder,
    IEnumerable<string> sourceKeywords, string message)
{
    var processedMessage = message;
    foreach (var apptReminder in sourceKeywords)
    {
        if (!processedMessage.Contains(apptReminder)) continue;

        var replaceValue = GetReminderInfo(reminder, apptReminder);
        processedMessage = processedMessage.Replace(apptReminder, replaceValue);
    }

    return processedMessage;
}

private static string GetReplacementValue(Resource resource,
    IEnumerable<string> sourceKeywords, string message)
{
    var processedMessage = message;
    foreach (var resourceKeyword in sourceKeywords)
    {
        if (!processedMessage.Contains(scheduleResourceKeyword)) continue;

        var replaceValue = GetResourceInfo(resource, resourceKeyword);
        processedMessage = processedMessage.Replace(resourceKeyword, replaceValue);
    }

    return processedMessage;
}
```

The main thing you'll notice is that each of the three helper methods is effectively performing the exact same function with the exception of which method they call to get the `replaceValue`. Is there a good way to combine these three methods into a single call without touching the underlying entities?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Actually it's a bit more complicated than that. You'll notice `processedMessage` getting passed around. It's actually not being overridden on each iteration of the loop, it's just further replacing values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about it, each `GetReplacementValue` has two responsibilities:

1. Enumerate through `sourceKeywords` to process `message`
2. Call some function to get the value to replace `message`'s data

Let's take out the second responsibility from there and make it reusable all at once:

```
private static string GetReplacementValue(Dictionary<string, string> replacementValues, string message)
{
    string processedMessage = message;

    foreach (var item in replacementValues)
    {
        processedMessage = processedMessage.Replace(item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    return processedMessage;
}
```

Now you only need to generate that Dictionary in a way that makes sense for the current `switch` case, for example:

```
case "User":
    if (userId.HasValue)
    {
        var user = _userRepository.GetById(userId);
        var replacementValues = sourcekeyWords
            .Where(x => processedMessage.Contains(x))
            // .Key will be the keyword and .Value will have the replacement value
            .ToDictionary(x => x, x => GetPatientInfoFromUser(user, x));

        processedMessage = GetReplacementValue(replacementValues, processedMessage);
    }

    break;
```

Comment: This looks like the right direction, but it may be a bit cumbersome for some of the replacements. All the replacements depend on properties of the object and some replacements require shaping (such as calculating the age).

Comment: @JDDavis Well, that was as far as your examples went. I was thinking of going farther but thought you most likely had more complicated calls that those `GetPatientInfoFromUser`